# How to check an array which has numers with discending order in C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I want to check if an array has number with discending order.
I can realize bubble sorting algorithm but I wonder how I can check if an array has numbers inside with discending order.

I want to get '1' if an array has numbers with discending numbers and '0' if the array is in the opposite case.

Here is a bubble sorting algorithm that I know :

```
for(int s = 0; s < num - 1; s++) {
        for(int t = s + 1; t < num; t++) {
            if(test[t] > test[s]) {     // ascending order
                int tmp = test[t];
                test[t] = test[s];
                test[s] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the example input and output.

example1)

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
>
> 0

example2)

> 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
>
> 1

example3)

> 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6
>
> 0

Comment: Can you think of some test that the array would fail if some numbers are ascending instead of descending?

Comment: @Tony Ruth 
Nope! Sadly, I can't understand the algorithm with ascending way too.

Comment: @starrykss your que is saying about only checking but your code is sorting it. why? please add some input case too.

Comment: @Tony Ruth 
I added some examples! Sorry to make you confused, I just wanted to let you know I know how to make an array with descending/ascending order from an array which has sporadic numbers.

Comment: @starrykss the bubblesort algorithm that you listed goes through the array and checks each pair of number to see if they are in the right order (ascending in this case). If they are not in order, then it swaps them. So, if any swap has occurred, then the array was not in order to begin with. Also, because of the transitive property, you do not need to check every pair of numbers, just go through the list once and check if each number is in the right order compared to the number after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you question is unclear,do you mean to check assending/descending order like follow

```
1 2 3 4 5 //asending
5 4 3 2 1 //descending
```

or

```
123 356 289 145 789 //asending within individual numbers

987 541 982 653 321 //descending within individual numbers
```

As it is case 1: (checking for descending order )

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){     //5 being the size in the example i<5-1
   if(test[i]<test[i+1]){
      return 0;         //will return 0 if there are ascending no/mixed no

   }

}
return 1;   //if all goes well , i.e meaning descending order will return 1
```

Full code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int func(int arr[]){
    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) {     //5 being the size in the example i<5-1
        if (arr[i]<arr[i + 1]) {
               return 0;         //will return 0 if there are ascending no/mixed no
        }
    }
    return 1;

}

int main()
{
    int arr[100];
    cout << "enter elements" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    cout << "result= " << func(arr) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is not an answer.

Comment: I wanted to know the first way. And I want to check if the numbers in the array are all with descending way. 

If the array has numbers like this {4, 3, 2, 1} then I should get '1' because it is descending order but I this case {4, 3, 2, 1, 3} should not be '1' because it is not with descending order fully.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  But I can't get 1 if I input {5, 4, 3, 2, 4}. This is my code that I used with your help! 

   for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    if (prices[k] > prices[k + 1]) {
     printf("1 \n");
    }
    else {
     printf("0 \n");
    }
   }
   return 1;

Comment: for (int k = 0; k < n-1; k++) // put n-1 instead of n

Comment: happy to help:)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to sort your array only for checking if the numbers are descending. Just go through your array and if element n is smaller than the n+1th element (then it's ascending) set the flag and step out of the loop.

```
int isDescending = 1;
int num = 10; //number of items in your Array

for(int n = 0; n < (num - 1); n++) {
  if (test[n] < test[n + 1]) {
   isDescending = 0;
   break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Put a flag in it
Like

```
  int k=0;


  for(int s = 0; s < num - 1; s++) {
            for(int t = s + 1; t < num; t++) {
                if(test[t] > test[s]) {     // ascending order
                    int tmp = test[t];
                    test[t] = test[s];
                    test[s] = tmp;
                    k=1;
                }
            }
        }
    if(k==1)
          cout<<"\n\tThe series was not in descending order.";
```

Comment: the que is about only checking. why are you sorting it?

Comment: I am sorry to make you confused. I want to say I don't need to sort the numbers! I just want to check if all numbers in the array are with descending way.

Comment: Then remove
 int tmp = test[t];
 test[t] = test[s];
 test[s] = tmp;
These statements.

Comment: Thank you for your help!! But I can't get 1 if I input {5, 4, 3, 2, 4}.

Comment: It will give 1.